# Wait for HttpRequest to finish before starting a new activity

Tags: java, android

so I am trying to learn how to create basic Android applications.

I am stuck on this problem: 
The Home Activity has a button that once pressed does two things: 
1. Call a REST-Api on my backend-server. The server returns JSON-Objects. The JSON objects are mapped to Java Objects. Finally they are added to a static list.

2. Start a new intent that launches an Activity with a List Layout.
   OnCreate() the ListLayout is filled with data from the static List obtained in step 1.

The Problem is that step 2 does not work as intended because step 1 is asynchronous.  So step 2 runs before step 1 finishes to fill the static list with data from the server, resulting in an empty List being displayed on the ListActivity.

How can I wait for step 1 to finish before starting the new Activity so the data is displayed correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AsyncTask`.

Inside the method `doInBackground()` put your code for performing API call. After the API call is completed, the method `onPostExecute()` gets called where you can put the code to go to the next activity.

Check detailed guide here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

Create an AsyncTask class and override their method as this example :

```
 public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{


  @Override
  public void onPreExecute()
  super.onPreExecute();
  {
  /// initialize loading animation if you want
  }

  @Override
  public String doInbackGround(String... params)
  {
          ///call your rest request 

           return resulofyourrequest;
  }

  @Override
  public void onPostExecute(String result)
  {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      // stop loading animation if you already started one in onPreExecute
      ///do the stuff you need after you get the result and start your activity here

  }

}
```

and to run your class

```
  new DownloadTask().execute(your_url);
```